# How can I filter results while displaying the list of collections in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

The "show collections" command shows the list of entire collection. I want to know if there is a way to list or search for specific collections using filters ?

E.g:

```
show collections

allocation
axis_selection
dummy
results
param_test
```

But I want only collections that start with 'a' (my filter)

```
show collections

allocation
axis_selection
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't modify what `show collections` command prints. But you can get collection names with [db.getCollectionNames()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#db.getCollectionNames) method and filter array of names manually:

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (c) { return c.indexOf('a') == 0; })
```

Comment: Can we use options of getCollectionName `{ listCollections: 1, filter: <document> }` for filter above scenario. Instead of JavaScript filter?